# Keras как определить к какому ответу привязан выходной персептрон

Tags: keras, tensorflow

Добрый день. У меня есть простейший `Keras` скрипт который учит 10 объектов. После обучения как определить что к чему относится? Учится с помощью `fit_generator` и работает с помощью `flow_from_directory`. Я читал что можно список создать с помощью `class_weight` но как это сделать не написано)) Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

P.S. Когда учил на кошках и собаках определить было легко. Подаёшь на вход он тебе отвечает с вероятностью на ошибку определить где собака а где кошка легко. А с 10 объектами и 80% распознавания сложно))

Comment: Можно использовать model.predict_generator для получения предсказаний после вызова flow_from_directory

Comment: Можете пояснить как это мне поможет узнать какой персептрон что отдаёт? Я нашёл пример 
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
    train_generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
print(bottleneck_features_train.shape)
Он отдаёт 300 10. Если убрать shape то он отдаёт массив от 0 до 1

Comment: Можно и убрать shape, но потом вызывать predictions = np.argmax(bottleneck_features_train , axis=-1) чтобы получить предсказания для категорий

Comment: Я прошу прощения за глупые вопросы. 
Аккуратность на тестовых данных: 100.00%
[5 6 3 9 9 3 6 8 3 8 3 3 0 0 9 5 6 2 9 2 6 7 2 6 2 3 7 7 1 9 8 1 5 6 1 8 9
 6 8 9 9 2 5 9 1 9 1 3 4 8 9 0 3 4 0 7 5 9 2 8 8 9 9 9 2 1 7 9 1 9 4 9 3 6
 5 2 3 9 5 1 3 0 8 4 3 3 8 8 0 9 5 4 8 9 4 9 2 9 9 5 4 2 9 1 6 9 1 8 9 8 8
 2 6 8 9]
После аккуратности идёт вывод predict_generator. Что мне с этим делать? Я понимаю что это ответы на картинки но Я не знаю на какие из каких папок они взяты ит.д. немного сократил вывод.

Comment: А можно код в вопрос добавить, а то непонятно?

Comment: Здесь немного не удобно с этим Я дам ссылку с тех пор код не сильно изменился.
http://www.cyberforum.ru/python-science/thread2207974.html